# Can ratios of unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind be simplified?

Tags: closed-form, fractions, stirling-numbers, analytic-combinatorics

**Motivation**

I am [looking](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409560/is-there-any-literature-on-sum-i-1k-left-k-atop-i-right-zetai1) into the series

$$\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n)^{2}-1) &= 1+ \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{H_{-\frac{1}{m}}}{m} \\ &= 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigg{(} \frac{1}{kk!} \bigg{(} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left[ {k \atop i} \right] \zeta(i+1) - k! \bigg{)}  \bigg{)}.  
\end{align} . $$

Therefore, I'm interested in the sum of Stirling-zeta values: $$S_{k} := \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \left[ {k \atop i} \right] \zeta(i+1). $$

It appears that no alternative expressions in terms of integrals are currently known for $S_{k}$. However, there are many such expressions that are equal or similar to the *reversed* Stirling zeta sums:

$$T_{k} := \sum_{i=1}^{k}{k \brack i}\zeta(k + 2-i). $$

For instance, when we define $E_{k} := \int_{0}^{1} \Big{(} \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1} \Big{)}^{k} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \Big{(} - \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} \Big{)}^k dx := F_{k}$, we [have](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262053/multiple-integral-evaluation-involving-stirling-numbers-and-riemann-zeta-functio): $$E_{k} = F_{k} = k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left[ k-1 \atop i\right]\zeta(k+1-i) . $$

**Question**

Suppose we could find a similar integral expression for the generating function $$E_{k}(x) := k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left[ k-1 \atop i\right]\zeta(k+1-i) x^{i} . $$

Furthermore, define $$S_{k} (x) := \sum_{i=1}^{k}{k \brack i}\zeta(i+1)x^{i}  $$

similarly. Then I thought it might be possible to transform $E_{k}(\cdot)$ into $S_{k}(\cdot)$ if one knows how to express $$f(k,i) := \frac{\left[ k \atop i\right] }{\left[ k \atop k- i\right] }  $$ succinctly in closed form.

It appears some [work](https://www.birs.ca/workshops/2016/16w5048/files/Kropf.pdf) on this has been done, but this seems to go more into approximations than into actual closed forms. So my question is:

> Can $f(k,i)$ be simplified into a succinct closed form?